# Convert a STRING to DATE data type in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT SaleDate, CAST(SaleDate AS DATE)
```

and also:

```
PARSE_DATE(SaleDate, '%mm/%dd/%YYYY')
```

But getting the following error:

```
Invalid date: '5/15/2014'
```

Seems like BigQuery doesn't recognize the data format..

Comment: parse_date first parameter is the pattern string see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date

Comment: Try `parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', saleDate)`

Comment: Also see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time for the correct format elements to use, as it should just be `%m/%d/%Y` not `%mm/%dd/%YYYY`

Comment: I've tried SELECT SaleDate, PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', SaleDate) AS FormattedSaleDate
FROM portfolio.nashville and also not working @Isolated

Comment: Not able to replicate your issue. Maybe you have varying formats. Check your data.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried the following:
> `SELECT SaleDate, CAST(SaleDate AS DATE)`

For this, you can use

```
SELECT SaleDate, CAST(SaleDate AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

> and also:
> `PARSE_DATE(SaleDate, '%mm/%dd/%YYYY')`

And for this one you can use

```
PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', SaleDate)
```